# Install APC on Debian 5.0

Tags: php, debian, alternative-php-cache

Is there a tutorial on how to install APC (Alternative PHP Cache on Debian 5.0).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for installing APC on Debian systems is to use the [dot.deb packages](http://www.dotdeb.org/).  The official [Debian APC package](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/php-apc) is still using version 3.0.19-2 which is very outdated.

Using the dot.deb package will also allow you to use the latest version of PHP.

### Instructions:

For the main Dotdeb repository, depending on your distribution (lenny/oldstable or squeeze/stable), add these two lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list file (choosing a mirror near you) :

**Squeeze :**

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
```

**Lenny :**

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org oldstable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org oldstable all
```

(Optional) If you’re running Debian 5.0 “Lenny” and you want PHP 5.3 instead of the default PHP 5.2, add these two additionnal lines too :

```
deb http://php53.dotdeb.org oldstable all
deb-src http://php53.dotdeb.org oldstable all
```

You don’t need this if you’re running Debian 6.0 “Squeeze” : PHP 5.3 is the default branch

Then fetch the appropriate GnuPG key

`wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg`

cat dotdeb.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

Run

```
apt-get update
```

You should now be able to use the Dotdeb packages with apt-get (or dselect, or aptitude as well…)

To install APC:

```
apt-get install php5-apc
```

Comment: I am using Squeeze and after following all your steps w/o a problem, the last step gives me this output, think you can help me? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7PFALCAs

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it via aptitude: *aptitude install php-apc*
Afterwars you can configure it in */etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini*
Have a look at [php-apc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/apc.configuration.php) for configuration options.

Otherwise you could use "pecl" to install it via *pecl install apc*. Prequisite is to have the  php5-dev module installed.

Comment: Hej shakalandy,i have tryed more time with

aptitude install php-apc
and pecl install apc

but i get resultat " Commant Not Found "
what should i do? Tnx

Comment: @DK-System if you don't have `aptitude` then use `apt-get install php-apc`.

Comment: Tnx it's works.